# videocodecs installation

Tags: upgrade

I try to install videocodecs in ubuntu 20.04 and I get these message -Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 85721 (apt). I am new in this and I don`t now what to do !Thanks !

Comment: Reboot the computer.

Comment: I'd suggest waiting a few minutes & trying again..  Unless you've got a command window or GUI window in another workspace etc making changes (ie. it's you that has the lock & created this condition), it'll resolve itself rather quickly..